Related to SNR in wireless communication
I am working on a research paper related to wireless communication, wherein I am facing some doubt while writing expression of SNR  (which is a ratio of Signal variance in numerator to Noise variance in denominator).
Let us consider a wireless communication scenario where a received signal over a random wireless channel is given by
$$ y= h_{1} s_{1} + h_{1} \phi_{h_{1}} s_{1} + w \tag{1} $$
where,
$h_1$ is random wireless channel, $h_1 \sim \mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2_{h_1})$,
$s_1$ is message signal and is modelled as $s_1 \sim \mathcal{N}(0,P_1)$ and $w$ is Gaussian noise modelled as $w\sim \mathcal{N}(0,N_w)$, $\phi_{h_1}$ is noise due to motion and is modelled as $\phi_{h_1}\sim \mathcal{C}\mathcal{N}(0, (1-\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)}))$ .
My query is which is the correct way to write the SNR expression eq.\eqref{2} or eq.\eqref{3}
$$\text{SINR} = \frac{|h_1|^2 P_1}{\sigma^2_{h_1}(1-\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)})N_w} \tag{2} \label{2} $$
$$\text{SINR} = \frac{|h_1|^2 P_1}{|h_1|^2(1-\rho_{h_1}^{2(n-1)})N_w} \tag{3} \label{3} $$
Please note that in equation \eqref{2}, I had written $\sigma^2_{h_1}$ in the denominator instead of $|h_1|^2$ as $h_1$ is associated with noise due to motion. So is it correct to write in this way?
Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank u so much sir for ur reply...That answer is not properly solving my query....could u please explain me here....

@Pranu- Sorry that comment was automatically generated. You posted the same question twice. Please delete this one and update your original one (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/93534/21048) if you want to modify the question.
